# Google Street View API returns 403 status for API keys with originating domain restriction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have signed up for the Google Street View Image API. I can grab images using the API with my API key when I copy the URL into a browser location bar. But when I try to programmatically load the image via jQuery, I get http code 403. For example, if I use something like:

```
$('#imgdiv').css('background-image','url("[streetview url with API key]");
```

Then the image won't load and the Javascript console says:

```
GET [streetview url with API key] 403 (OK)
```

It doesn't appear to be a rate limiting issue as far as I can tell. I've probably only requested 1-200 images so far. And I can type that same URL into my browser and it comes up. The domain with the code loading these images is verified.

UPDATE:

I tried using an API key without originating domain restrictions and that works fine. So it appears my problem is in specifying the originating domain. When generating the key I used `*.mydomain.com/*` but that isn't working. My domain doesn't have a preceeding `www` on it (e.g. it's only `mydomain.com`). Could that be the issue?

Ideas?

Comment: Can you show us an actual URL you're using?  Maybe setup a simple version on JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem

Comment: thanks that got me to try more things. see update above; it appears to be a problem with the originating domain specification.

Comment: That could very well be the issue

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10370) with Google Maps API on this precise behaviour but have yet to hear back